# How do I force a reconfiguration of projects in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have a build.gradle file that calls some SVNKit stuff to `svn export` some directories that make up a Gradle multi-project.

I have a task dedicated to doing this that looks something like this:

```
task checkoutIntoDir() << {
  mkdir 'dirForSvnProjects_2014_07_17_19_50' // timestamp not hard-coded ;)
  // prompt for username/password
  // run svn export which places projects in dirForSvnProjects_2014_07_17_19_50
}
```

with another `GradleBuild` task that depends on it:

```
task buildCheckedOutStuff(type: GradleBuild, dependsOn: checkoutIntoDir) {
  dir = "dirForSvnProjects_2014_07_17_19_50/svnProjectIExported"
  tasks = ['buildMyProj']
}
```

But it says `task 'buildMyProj' not found in root project` when it gets there. Now if I take out the task dependency `checkoutIntoDir` and run it on a directory that's there before I start the build, it works fine. I'm guessing I need to run some kind of "reconfiguration" to make the project aware of the new gradle project in `dirForSvnProjects_2014_07_17_19_50`?

Comment: Not sure how it would cause your problems but your checkoutIntoDir as written will be running at configuration time, not execution time

Comment: are you sure your checkoutIntoDir task is working? What happens if you take out the dependency and then run `gradle checkoutIntoDir buildCheckedOutEquip'?

Comment: I'll try that when I get back to my desk, thanks.

Comment: Sorry about it being wrong, but I actually did have the `<<` on my `checkoutIntoDir` task, so it will be run at runtime, not configuration time. Perryn was correct as it was originally submitted to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

It was actually related to the way I was setting variables, not about Gradle.

I had a `createDir` task defined that set a variable that was defined (but not set) at the "root" level of the script. It looked something like this:

```
def myBuildDir

task createDir << {
  def nowDate = String.format('%tY_%<tm_%<td_%<tH_%<tM',Calendar.instance)
  myBuildDir= "_build_$nowDate"
  mkdir myBuildDir
}

task checkoutIntoDir(dependsOn: createDir) << {
  // prompt for username/password
  // run svn export which places projects in myBuildDir
}
```

And as Perryn Fowler pointed out in the comments, any block that's not in a `doLast` (or the `<<` shorthand)-type block will be run at configuration time when `createDir` was being run at runtime. Therefore the variable was not set for the `buildCheckedOutStuff` task.

So I just changed it to set the date at the root as well and it worked:

```
def nowDate = String.format('%tY_%<tm_%<td_%<tH_%<tM',Calendar.instance)
def eqipBuildDir = "_build_$nowDate"

task createDir << {
  mkdir eqipBuildDir
}
```

That's what I get for leaving out pieces for brevity!